# IBOutletCollection of UIButtons wont set highlighted

Tags: ios5, uibutton, permanent, iboutletcollection, setstate

I have an IBOutletCollection of UIButtons:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableArray *Buttons;
```

with an ibaction i would to change the highlighted state permanently after the touch down event.

This Problem is very similar to this:
[IBOutletCollection of UIButtons - changing selected state of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888422/iboutletcollection-of-uibuttons-changing-selected-state-of-buttons)

... but with the for-loop the buttons doesnt change.

i also tried the perfomselector method from here: [Keep iPhone UIButton Highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290534/keep-iphone-uibutton-highlighted)

but it doesnt work.

now my code:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButtons:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger Index = [button tag];
    [[Buttons objectAtIndex:Index] setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

if i change line four to this:

```
    [[Buttons objectAtIndex:3] setHighlighted:YES];
```

it works for the fourth element in my collection... But not with the index variable....

regards, phil

### Update

**SelectionViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SelectionViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableArray *Buttons;

- (IBAction)toggleButtons:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SelectionViewController.m**

```
#import "SelectionViewController.h"

@interface SelectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation SelectionViewController

@synthesize Buttons;


-(IBAction)toggleButtons:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    NSUInteger Index = [button tag];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];

    [[Buttons objectAtIndex:Index] setHighlighted:YES];
}
- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton *)b {
    [b setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

[image: XIB File]

**Okey Update 2:**

Now i had declared my Buttons as normal IBOutlet and this is not working:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButtons:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;

    [button setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

But if change it to this:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButtons:(id)sender
{    
    [myOutletButton setHighlighted:YES]; //Normal Outlet 
}
```

it works....

But why is not possible with the sender?

regards!

**Update 3**

This works also:

```
for(id button in self.view.subviews)
{
    [button setHighlighted:YES];

}
```

Ok if change the delay time in the selector to 1, the state will be highlighted. I am using "touch down" event... i think after i touched up the button gets its old state. Which event is the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your example works with a specific integer, the problem is probably that the *tag* property is not set properly for each of your buttons.  If the buttons are created in interface builder, each of them will have a default tag value of 0.  To check this, click on the button and then, in the Attributes Inspector, scroll down to View and see what value is entered in the *tag* field

Comment: hey john, the tag property is set properly. I printed it to console and it was correct. could it be the an allocation problem of the uibuttons? should i allocate the buttons especially?

Comment: You should check that each button has a link to the Buttons IBOutletCollection.  In Interface Builder, right click on each button and make sure that Buttons is listed under Referencing Outlet Collections.  If it is not, control-drag from it to the IBOutlet in your ViewController header file.

Comment: Can't really do any more without seeing all the code. Happy to take a look if you can paste a link

Comment: Ok i had tested it with with normal IBOutlets and having the same problem.

Comment: You should use the "Touch Up Inside" event.  This is the default for buttons.  I tested your code using this and it seems to work OK.  (By the way, you don't need the call to **[[Buttons objectAtIndex ... ** if you are using the **PerformSelector** call)

Comment: FYI  ioS automatically highlights button on touch (try it on a button with no actions attached).  If you use the _Touch Down_ event, your message is sent, but then the button is unhighlighted by default on the _Touch Up_ event. If you use the _Touch Up Inside_ event, your message is sent after the system message, and so has the desired effect.